# Angular subscription on observable returns undefined

Tags: javascript, angular

My Service

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable, of } from "rxjs";
import { SearchResult } from "../Components/container-search/Models/SearchResult";
import { environment } from "../../environments/environment";
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class ContainerService {
  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {}

  private SearchResults: SearchResult[] = [];
  public headers = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    }),
  };

  public Search(): Observable<SearchResult[]> {
    if (this.SearchResults.length === 0) {
       this.http
        .get<SearchResult[]>(
          environment.endpointURL + "/FooBar/Search",
          this.headers
        )
        .subscribe((x) => {
          this.SearchResults = x;
          return of(this.SearchResults);
        });
    } else {
      return of(this.SearchResults);
    }
  }
}
```

When I call Search() in my component it returns

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined`

My calling code is

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
     this.searchService.Search().subscribe((x) => {
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<SearchResult>(x);
    });
  }
```

Can someone explain why this code `this.searchService.Search()` would always return with the above error?

Comment: You are already subscribe in service

Comment: @pc_coder, i thought returning the observable from the subscription would be ok. What should I do instead?

Comment: This is async call so you can take your subscibe from service to component.Then it will work. Also you can make control for length in component too. In service just send request and return response

Comment: @pc_coder, I want to cache that data in the service, then check if the cached data exists. If it doesnt make the HTTP call if it does exist i want to return the cached value. how should i do that?

Comment: Avoid subscriptions in services if possible. If you need to save the response, then you could use the pipe function and an operator like tap or map and assign the response to your variable inside the service. (http.get().pipe(tap((x) => { ... }));

Comment: I agree @sombrerogalaxy You can also use pipe rather than subscribe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.subscribe` call is returning an `Observable`, but that isn't what's being returned by the `Search` method. The subscription is an asynchronous process. The `subscribe` kicks off that process and only reacts when the http call returns, but the `Search` method keeps executing and returns undefined.

The below code will return the `Observable` from the http call directly and fix your issue.

```
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

public Search(): Observable<SearchResult[]> {
    if (this.SearchResults.length === 0) {
       return this.http
        .get<SearchResult[]>(
          environment.endpointURL + "/FooBar/Search",
          this.headers
        ).pipe(tap(x => this.SearchResults = x));
    } else {
      return of(this.SearchResults);
    }
  }
```

Comment: This code does work, but It doesnt Cache the SearchResults in the services. My End game is to cache the results in the services and then return the cached results

Comment: But your else condition will fail here . You cant get else condition's subscribe

Comment: @pc_coder I'm not sure what you mean. `of` creates an Observable and therefor could be subscribed to.

Comment: Ahh sorry didn't noticed of .

Comment: @peinearydevelopment thank you very much for the help!